# Generating a url from form submissions

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a final in my coding class and these are the requirements:

1. Enter a company's stock symbol. e.g. MSFT (Microsoft), or GOOG (Alphabet) into the text
   field
2. Select the chart they wish to view from the select tag with 5 options. The various options are
   detailed below.
3. Click the button to display the specified stock chart for the given company using the IMG tag
   within the web page.
   To get a stock chart from Yahoo, you must use the following URL format:
   https://chart.yahoo.com/z?t=**chart_code**&s=**stock_symbol**
   where stock_symbol is the stock symbol for the company whose chart you wish to view, and
   chart_code is one of the following codes:

   - 1d - 1 day chart
   - 5d - 5 day chart
   - 1m - 1 month chart
   - 6m - 6 month chart
   - 1y - 1 year chart

My problem is generating the url from the data the the user inputs. I have a text box and a selection field, but I'm not sure how to have that data submitted in a way that changes chart_code and stock_symbol so I can generate the url to match the entered data. I was thinking that maybe a function would be best, but I'm not really sure how to go about it.

My code so far

```
<html>
<head>
        <title></title>
<script>
function DemStocks() {


}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type= "text" name="Company" value="Who?">

    </form>
<select name="timechart">
    <option value="1d">1 day</option>
    <option value="5d">5 day</option>
    <option value="1m">1 month</option>
    <option value="6m">6 months</option>
    <option value="1y">1 year</option>
</select>
<button type="button" onclick="DemStocks" value="$$$$">

<script>


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your HTML? You'll get more help if we don't have to guess what your current stuff looks like. Also include any Javascript or CSS that you feel is relevant to solving the problem.

Comment: Do you know how to have JS get the value of an `<input>` or `<select>`?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of those and create your url like this:

```
function DemStocks() {
   var url = "?t= $("#timechart").val();
   url += "&s="+ $("#company").val();
   location.href += url;
}
```

And remember that I am using an id selector in jQuery so you have to add it to your html:

```
<input type= "text" id="company" name="Company" value="Who?">

<select name="timechart" id="timechart">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few tips to get you on your way:

First, the `onclick` of a `<button>` isn't just the name of a function, it needs to be a complete JS statement. To have it call your function, use this: `onclick="DemStocks()"` (note the parentheses)

The easiest way to get the values of your input elements (`input` and `select`, in your case) is to give them unique `id`s and then use `document.getElementById("the_elements_id").value`. This will return the text content of your `input`, or the `value` attribute of the `select`ed `option`.

To assemble the URL, use `+` to concatenate strings, e.g.

```
var url = "https://chart.yahoo.com/z?t="+chart_code+"&s="+stock_symbol;
```

Good luck!